# Unity text box refuses to update with a c# script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a text box on a scene in unity. At the point with the issue, the text box already has a few separate lines of text.

**The script is as follows:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class GameEngine : MonoBehaviour {

//Game level variables:

public bool TutorialDone = false;
public int TutorialCount = 0;
bool isticking = false;
Text outputtext;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {        
    outputtext = GameObject.Find("ConsoleOutputScroll/Viewport/Output").GetComponent<Text>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {        

}

//Process inputted text and splits into commands, validation etc.
public void processtext(string inputstring)
{
    if(inputstring == "")
    {
        commandin("blank");
        return;
    }

    commandin("something");
    return;
}

//Process any commands supplied, apply these to game stages
public void commandin(string commandtype)
{
    if(TutorialDone == false)
    {
        tutorialrun();
        return;
    }        
}

//Tutorial procedure
public void tutorialrun()
{     
    switch (TutorialCount)
    {            
        case 0:
            TutorialCount++;
            outputnewline("***CRITICAL SYSTEM FAILURE*** Press any key to exit...");
            break;
        case 1:
            TutorialCount++;
            outputnewline("***CRITICAL SYSTEM FAILURE*** Press any key to exit...");
            break;
        case 2:
            TutorialCount++;
            outputnewline("***CRITICAL SYSTEM FAILURE*** Press any key to exit...");
            break;
        case 3:
            TutorialCount++;
            outputnewline("***CRITICAL SYSTEM FAILURE*** Press any key to exit...");
            break;
        case 4:
            TutorialCount++;
            outputnewline("***CRITICAL SYSTEM FAILURE*** Press any key to exit...");
            break;
        case 5:
            TutorialCount++;
            outputnewline("***CRITICAL SYSTEM FAILURE*** Press any key to exit...");
            break;
        case 6:
            TutorialCount++;
            tickertypenewline("ESTABLISHING CONNECTION...");
            break;
    }
}

//Appends to the console output on a new line
public void outputnewline(string inputstring)
{
    string Temp;
    Temp = outputtext.text + inputstring + Environment.NewLine;
    outputtext.text = Temp;
}

//Clears output and adds new text
public void outputclear(string inputstring)
{
    outputtext.text = inputstring + Environment.NewLine;
}

//Typewriter style text addition on a new line
public void tickertypenewline(string inputstring)
{
    //Exit if we are already ticking
    if (isticking)
    {
        return;
    }

    isticking = true;
    StartCoroutine(tickertypeco(inputstring));
}

//Typewriter style text after clearing output
public void tickertypeclear(string inputstring)
{
    outputtext.text = "";
    StartCoroutine(tickertypeco(inputstring));
}

//Typewriter generator
IEnumerator tickertypeco(string inputstring)
{
    //outputtext.text = "sugar";
    WaitForSeconds waitTime = new WaitForSeconds(0.125f);
    foreach (char c in inputstring)
    {
        string temp = outputtext.text + c.ToString();
        outputtext.text = temp;
        yield return waitTime;
    }        
    isticking = false;
}
```

This simply doesn't appear to do anything. If I clear the text box beforehand it doesn't appear to do anything. However if I clear and then add a random string without any new lines or spaces, it then behaves correctly. The outcome should be a typed effect on the string as it enters the text box.

Can't seem to work out where the fault is with this.

Can someone help please? :)

Programmer :) : Your reworked code is in there, I have only changed the name from tickerText to outputtext. It still does not work, I have now included the entire GameEngine script, hopefully you find something obvious in there I have missed. :). Many thanks for keeping having a look for me.

Answer (score 0):

Even with the `Text` box cleared, your code still functioned properly on my side.

I suspect that the `tickertypestr` variable is being modified from another function while the `tickertypeco()` function is still running. This is possible because `tickertypestr` is a global variable. This can happen while the function is waiting due to `WaitForSeconds(0.125f)`.

**FIX**:

**1**.Make the `tickertypeco` coroutine function take `string` as parameter just like the `tickertypenewline` function. Pass the string from the `tickertypenewline` function to the `tickertypeco` function.

In order to pass parameter into a coroutine function without boxing/boxing it, you must use the

```
Coroutine StartCoroutine(IEnumerator routine);
```

overload instead of

```
Coroutine StartCoroutine(string methodName);
```

You will also be able to stop that coroutine with it.

**2**. Also, add a flag to make sure that there is only one instance of that coroutine running at a time. This will prevent weird problems such as the Text box showing weird Texts since it's been modified from different places.

**3**.`GameObject.Find` should not be used in a loop on the-same GameObject. Do that once then cache it. For your scenario, caching the `Text` component is better. Since you know the wait time(0.125f), you should declare `WaitForSeconds` outside the for loop then use it inside it.

***#1*** and **#2** combined should fix your problem. **#3** is just optional.

Below is what the code should look like:

```
Text tickerText;
bool isTicking = false;

void Start()
{
    tickerText = GameObject.Find("ConsoleOutputScroll/Viewport/Output").GetComponent<Text>();

    tickertypenewline("ESTABLISHING CONNECTION...");
}

public void tickertypenewline(string inputstring)
{
    //Exit if we are already ticking
    if (isTicking)
    {
        return;
    }

    //Not ticking so start ticking now
    isTicking = true;
    StartCoroutine(tickertypeco(inputstring));
}

IEnumerator tickertypeco(string tickerString)
{
    WaitForSeconds waitTime = new WaitForSeconds(0.125f);

    foreach (char c in tickerString)
    {
        string temp = tickerText.text + c.ToString();
        tickerText.text = temp;
        yield return waitTime;
    }

    //Done ticking, set to false
    isTicking = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I have updated my code and edited my question. Unfortunately, it is still not working.

Comment: Your updated code is **not** the-same code I had. Please fix that. Look at the `tickertypeco` function, They are still different from mine. Also, why not create new script, copy my code to it, Disable other scripts then try it and see what happens. If it works then modify it and add your other code to it.

Comment: Thanks for that Programmer. I have compared the two functions and they are identical apart from different naming. I have used "outputtext" as opposed to "tickerText" etc. The only other difference is the line which adds a new line at the end of the function. As explained above, this is simply to try and further investigate the issue. This is no longer there.

Comment: I appreciate what you are saying about creating a new script with everything stripped back but that is almost guaranteed to work and then when I add my code back in, the issue will more than likely arise again. From what I can see my code looks perfectly fine, do you have any ideas as to what might be causing it. Did you catch my information above about the number of characters affecting etc.? Very strange.

Comment: The  updated `tickertypeco` function from the `GameEngine`  class has `GameObject.Find` in it. Mine does not. Please update it to look like what I have in my answer. Like I said before, I do **not** want you to delete your other scripts. I simply asked you to **disable** all GameObjects. Create a simple script and put that code in my answer into it. Attach that code to an empty Object and run it. Tell me if it works or not. I simply want to make sure that this is not a bug and I want to be sure that this is a problem with your code.

Comment: I will try that when I get home. However there is an edit in my question above that shows the latest version of the tickertypeco function. It is identical to yours with only different names and the extra line for testing. I will try that as soon as I can. Many thanks.

Comment: Ok so I disabled all other scripts and attached a new script with your code and nothing else and it works as it should. I have had a look through the script that this code is a part of and there is nothing else that interferes with the textbox in question. The rest of the functions just pass variables. The only other scripts that operate on the text box are a content fitter and a custom script for making sure the box is always scrolled to the bottom. Bit stumped now....is there anything else I could show that may help?

Comment: Ok. That's all I wanted to know. I am now sure that this script is working properly and no Unity version conflict. Remember this was the original script in your question and what I did was to fix the code inside each function. I did not rename of the functions.

Comment: Please go ahead and update the `tickertypeco` function in your current `GameEngine` script with the exact code in my `tickertypeco` function. Copy everything inside the `tickertypeco` function and paste it in your original code. At the-same time, update your question to reflect your latest `GameEngine` script. Let me know what happens